# Exception error in method not using exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm having an issue

**TEST CODE:**

```
    addList.add("Task 30", 30);

    System.out.println(addList.get
```

**NOTE:** For whatever reason the method actuallly using the exception has no compiler errors but the one that doesn't use it is. Why is that?

Comment: What errors do you get? What lines cause the errors?

Comment: Please show the errors. It will also help a little if you show the class which contains the test code.

Comment: What is the declaration of `OrderedList.add()`?

Comment: Yes...that whole line (or more) up to the opening {

Comment: I suggest that you read more about exceptions. In particular, [this official tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) will help you understand what is happening here and how to fix it.

Comment: The full tutorial can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: *This is my first time posting on here*. Hmm... [really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023011/exception-created-in-one-class-used-in-another)

Comment: You should really read the tutorial as suggested by @Code-Apprentice

Comment: You definitely need to read the first link I gave. It explains exactly why you get the errors.

Comment: @D.Hoffman I don't think you _are_ aware of how try/catch blocks work.  To put it simply, if method A calls method B, and method B has a `throws` clause, you need to tell the compiler what method A should _do_ with the exception if it gets thrown.  That means that EITHER method A needs a `throws` clause of its own, OR method A needs a `try` and `catch` for the exception.  Your `testGet` has neither.

Comment: Because `throws OrderedListException` at the top of the    `add` method means "throws an OrderedListException"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testAdd()` does not have any errors because you `catch` the exception. `testGet()` gives errors because you do not have a `catch` nor do you declare that the method can `throw` the exception. For more details about exceptions, read [the official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/), particularly the section on [catch or specify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html).

Comment: @D.Hoffman Then you need to read the links I gave. Note that the **add()** method causes the errors, not the get() method.

Comment: @D.Hoffman There is nothing wrong with the `add()` method per se. The problem here is that the `add()` method declares that it throws an exception. Java requires every method which calls `add()` to `catch` the exception or declare it.

Comment: @D.Hoffman This requirement is the reason for the error messages. You have two ways to solve the error message, just as it states. A third solution is to remove the `throws` clause from the `add()` method.

Comment: @D.Hoffman If you need further help, you need to [edit] your question to show the `add()` method.

Comment: I think I got it. I updated the question with my new testGet that doesn't get any errors. Thanks for guiding me through it!